# CSV data to Timestamp conversion

Tags: timestamp

I am having this format in csv :2012-11-05T00:23:40.176-08:00 .I am loading this data to a table having timestamp as data type.So, it is throwing error. What is the correct strategy to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract the date from the variabile

```
var a = "2012-11-05T00:23:40.176-08:00"
var dateValue = a.split("T")[0];
```

If you want to convert a timestamp string to timestamp data type just use:

```
new Date("2012-11-05T00:23:40.176-08:00").getTime()
```